# Using FormCollection to store values from form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, formcollection

I have a HTML Form page that sends data to my ActionResult

The form has 1 to x amount of fields based on the size of the user shopping cart.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddToShoppingCart","ExpertEstimatorController")" method="post" name="shoppingCart">
    <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="sampleUser" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Password" value="BadPassword" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item1" value="Apple">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity1" value="30">

    <input type="hidden" name="item2" value="Orange">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity2" value="12">

    <input type="hidden" name="item3" value="Peach">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity3" value="19">

    //size varies on shopping cart can be 1 item to x amount of items
</form>
```

I want to be able to loop through all fields and store them in their own variable

I been hard coding it and it is very inefficient

```
    public ActionResult AddToShoppingCart(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection col)
    {
        string username = col["Username"];
        string password = col["Password"];

        string item1= col["item1"];
        string Qty1 = col["quantity1"];

        string item2 = col["item2"];
        string Qty2 = col["quantity2"];

        string item3= col["item3"];
        string Qty3 = col["quantity3"];

        string item4= col["item4"];
        string Qty4 = col["quantity4"];

        // 1 to x amount items 

        return ShoppingCartPage();
    }
```

I tried using

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var key in col.AsQueryable())
        {
            list.Add(col.Get(key.ToString()));
        }
```

to store each value into a list but I can't seem to get it to work

Essentially I am just trying to run through each value and store it for later

Comment: Why use FormCollection? Why not generate the form fields on the client side with the proper names and then take advantage of the model binder in MVC to create the object for you?

Comment: Its a 3rd party app that I have no control over, that is sending over a Html File that I have to to use to fill in a shopping cart

Answer (score 0):

You need this.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (var key in col.AllKeys)
{
   var value = col[key];
   list.Add(value);
}
```

or

```
foreach (var key in col.Keys)
{
   var value = col[key.ToString()];
   list.Add(value);
}
```